# Panel for drawing graphics and scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, panel

I want to be able to use a `Panel` or similar to draw graphics onto a Winform. I cannot seem to see anything regarding adding scrollbars if the graphics become larger than the control?

Is it possible to do this with a `Panel` or is there a similar control that will allow it?

Comment: WHy would somebody downvote this?  It's a perfectly reasonable question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set the AutoScroll property to true and the AutoScrollMinSize property to the size of the image.  The scrollbars will now automatically appear when the image is too large.

You'll want to inherit your own class from Panel so that you can set the DoubleBuffered property to true in the constructor.  Flicker would be noticeable otherwise.  Some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ImageBox : Panel {
    public ImageBox() {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    private Image mImage;
    public Image Image {
        get { return mImage; }
        set {
            mImage = value;
            if (value == null) this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, 0);
            else {
                var size = value.Size;
                using (var gr = this.CreateGraphics()) {
                    size.Width = (int)(size.Width * gr.DpiX / value.HorizontalResolution);
                    size.Height = (int)(size.Height * gr.DpiY / value.VerticalResolution);
                }
                this.AutoScrollMinSize = size;
            }
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        if (mImage != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, 0, 0);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I'll give this a go now.

Comment: Sorry Hans....the image that will fit into the panel is created dynamically at run time.  The graphics are created depending upon certain parameters.  Would this still work?

Comment: Yah, assign the Image property.  Works as well at design time as at run time.

Comment: The way I create the image is using graphics to draw circles on a panel.  Would i save this panel as an image?  Sorry the maybe silly questions - i'm totally new to graphics/image programming.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just do the drawing in the OnPaint() method.  The TranslateTransform call there makes sure that your drawing is properly scrolled.  You will however have to set the AutoScaleMinSize property yourself.

Comment: Maybe something has changed between when this question was asked and now, but how come even the base Panel object does not have the DoubleBuffered property for me to access in Visual Studio Intellisense? I'm using VS2012 and .NET 4.5 if that matters, and I can still set AutoScroll.

Comment: Shows up just fine when I try it.  Clearly you'll need to click the Ask Question button and document your question properly.

Comment: I have a problem - I am trying to display 1024x768 jpg using your code in 512x512 panel, unfortunately when I scroll I cannot scroll to the end of image (horizontally and vertically). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609430/winform-not-scrolling-when-drawing-objects-on-it) that might help you.

You could also try using a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) that you would manually change its size as the graphics get larger. Then set your form AutoScroll to true.

Comment: I would not use the picturebox as a canvas for drawing. The picturebox is only for displaying pictures. See i.e. Bob Powell's article regarding this exact issue.