# How do I remove the bitmap from a custom control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, bitmap, panel

I have a form that is loaded with a generated bitmap.  I want the user to be able to press a button and change the graphic displayed.  My question is, how can I delete the bitmap that is currently displayed?

Edit:  The bitmap is loading onto an ImageBox (not directly onto the form) Which was kindly suggested by Hans Passant  [c# panel for drawing graphics and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same principle as leppie's answer. Except that you need to set the `ImageBox.Image` property instead:

```
myImageBox.Image = null;
```

This works because of the following code (excerpted from [Hans's answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling/4306333#4306333)):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    if (mImage != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, 0, 0);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

When you set the control's `Image` property to `null`, the property setter forces the control to repaint itself (`this.Invalidate();`). When it repaints itself, no image is drawn  because the `OnPaint` method that is responsible for painting the control verifies that `mImage != null` before drawing it.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
Form.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't work as the bitmap is not loaded directly to the form.  Please see my edit above.  Thanks.