# How can I capture a drawing of a panel in winform to bitmap and save it to SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, bitmap, panel

I also want to display in a datagridview. I tried searching here and tried for hours to do it in all kinds of ways turning it to bitmap through drawtobitmap method and then turning it to a bite array and saving it to database
the database shows me 0X89 what does it mean?

And it doesn't show me the image on a datagridview

Can someone just give me a code that works and I'll improvise thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your name with us.

Comment: you need to convert the byte array to image before you display it to datagridview

Comment: try this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

For Saving

```
 Bitmap bmp =new Bitmap(panel1.Width,panel1.Height);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] result = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Seek(0,System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ms.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
```

and save result  to your sqlserver table

and to Convert Byte array to image use this

```
  public static Bitmap ConvertBinaryDataToImage(byte[] buffer)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            return bmap;
        }
```