# How to avoid flickering of graphic object when drawn on picture box in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

I am not good at graphic plotting in C#. I am trying to do an animated plotting of a rectangular point on an Image in PictureBox. However, I am facing some flickering issues, I couldn't find the way; how to resolve this issue.

```
g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), 10, 10);

Thread.Sleep(20);
invalidate_pictureBox1();
update_pictureBox1();
```

I have studied from other forums that this issue can be resolved using Timer instead of Thread sleep but don't know how to do it.

Comment: I need urgently a coffee so your question has to wait for a moment.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-sharp-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling) and go over https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bwinforms%5D+timer+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ayes

Comment: Don't use `CreateGraphics`... Use the `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` property and do your drawing in the `OnPaint` event. Also, what is the intended purpose of the `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @pinkfloxydx33 I used thread sleep because I use this block of my code in a thread

Comment: Thank you  @halfer next I will be careful while next posting question..

Comment: You need to tell us more about the thread! From other than the UI thread you need to `Invoke` updates of controls! Note that anything drawn from a control.CreateGrapgics object is wiped out at each refresh ()aka non-prsistent' drawing; good for rubberbands, bad otherwise). Hence the flicker..

Answer (score 0):

Draw what you want in Image of PictureBox, not on PictureBox control:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), 10, 10);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }
```

**EDIT**

if you want to draw on PictureBox control without flickering, put your drawing on `pictureBox1.Paint` event as follow:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Solution
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(delegate(object sender2, PaintEventArgs e2)
        {
            e2.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, x, y, 10, 10);
        });

        // Test
        buttonTest1.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
        {
            x++;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        });

        buttonTest2.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Width - 10; x++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        });

        buttonTest3.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender3, EventArgs e3)
            {
                if (x <= pictureBox1.Width - 10)
                    x++;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            });
            t.Enabled = true;
            t.Interval = 50;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply hussein, but I wonder at one point where should I call this timer event to put the delay in my program??

Comment: OP states he want to have an animation so drawng onto the control is the way to go. But only via the Paint event and its e.Graphics object.

Comment: The timer event is called repeatedly afer at least Interval ms as long as the Timer is active. To trigger the Paint event you invoke an Invalidate of the PBox..

Comment: Thank you and excuse me if I did not get it right. Try edited version...