# How to use PrintDocument with a scrollable Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, graphics

How do I use `PrintDocument` with a scrollable panel`?

Here is some of my code:

```
MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, 
pnl.Height));

Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - 
(pannel.Width / 2), pannel.Location.Y);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# panel for drawing graphics and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-sharp-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve], for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247750/edit) so that includes an MCVE, explain what you've tried so far, what the code you have does, how that's different from what you want it to do, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @AnantDabhi: your proposed duplicate has nothing at all to do with _printing_, something that this question is clearly asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These sets of methods allow to print the content of a [ScrollableControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol) to a Bitmap.

A description of the procedure:

1. The control is first scrolled back to the origin (`control.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);` (an exception is raised otherwise: the Bitmap has a wrong size. You may want to store the current scroll position and restore it after).
2. Verifies and stores the actual size of the Container, returned by the [PreferredSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.preferredsize) or [DisplayRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.displayrectangle) properties (depending on the conditions set by the method arguments and the type of container printed). This property considers the full extent of a container.
   This will be the size of the Bitmap.
3. Clears the Bitmap using the background color of the Container.
4. Iterates the **`ScrollableControl.Controls`** collection and prints all first-level child controls in their relative position (a child Control's `Bounds` rectangle is relative to the container ClientArea.)
5. If a first-level Control has children, calls the **`DrawNestedControls`** recursive method, which will enumerate and draw all nested child Containers/Controls, preserving the internal clip bounds.

**Includes support for RichTextBox controls**.
The **`RichEditPrinter`** class contains the logic required to print the content of a RichTextBox/RichEdit control. The class sends an [`EM_FORMATRANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-formatrange) message to the RichTextBox, using the Device context of the Bitmap where the control is being printed.
More details available in the MSDN Docs: [How to Print the Contents of Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/printing-rich-edit-controls?).

---

The **`ScrollableControlToBitmap()`** method takes only a **`ScrollableControl`** type as argument: you cannot pass a TextBox control, even if it uses ScrollBars.

▶ Set the **`fullSize`** argument to `true` or `false` to include all child controls inside a Container or just those that are visible. If set to `true`, the Container's `ClientRectangle` is expanded to include and print all its child Controls.

▶ Set the **`includeHidden`** argument to `true` or `false` to include or exclude the hidden control, if any.

---

**Note**: this code uses the [Control.DeviceDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.devicedpi) property to evaluate the current Dpi of the container's Device Context. This property requires .Net Framework 4.7+. If this version is not available, you can remove:

```
bitmap.SetResolution(canvas.DeviceDpi, canvas.DeviceDpi);
```

or derive the value with other means. See [GetDeviceCaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps).
Possibly, update the Project's Framework version :)

---

```
// Prints the content of the current Form instance, 
// include all child controls and also those that are not visible
var bitmap = ControlPrinter.ScrollableControlToBitmap(this, true, true);

// Prints the content of a ScrollableControl inside a Form
// include all child controls except those that are not visible
var bitmap = ControlPrinter.ScrollableControlToBitmap(this.panel1, true, false);
```

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ControlPrinter
{
    public static Bitmap ScrollableControlToBitmap(ScrollableControl canvas, bool fullSize, bool includeHidden)
    {
        canvas.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
        if (includeHidden) {
            canvas.SuspendLayout();
            foreach (Control child in canvas.Controls) {
                child.Visible = true;
            }
            canvas.ResumeLayout(true);
        }

        canvas.PerformLayout();
        Size containerSize = canvas.DisplayRectangle.Size;
        if (fullSize) {
            containerSize.Width = Math.Max(containerSize.Width, canvas.ClientSize.Width);
            containerSize.Height = Math.Max(containerSize.Height, canvas.ClientSize.Height);
        }
        else {
            containerSize = canvas.ClientSize;;
        }
         
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(containerSize.Width, containerSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        bitmap.SetResolution(canvas.DeviceDpi, canvas.DeviceDpi);

        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        if (canvas.BackgroundImage != null) {
            graphics.DrawImage(canvas.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, containerSize));
        }
        else {
            graphics.Clear(canvas.BackColor);
        }

        var rtfPrinter = new RichEditPrinter(graphics);

        try {
            DrawNestedControls(canvas, canvas, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, containerSize), bitmap, rtfPrinter);
            return bitmap;
        }
        finally {
            rtfPrinter.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void DrawNestedControls(Control outerContainer, Control parent, Rectangle parentBounds, Bitmap bitmap, RichEditPrinter rtfPrinter)
    {
        for (int i = parent.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var ctl = parent.Controls[i];
            if (!ctl.Visible || (ctl.Width < 1 || ctl.Height < 1)) continue;

            var clipBounds = Rectangle.Empty;
            if (parent.Equals(outerContainer)) { clipBounds = ctl.Bounds; }
            else {
                Size scrContainerSize = parentBounds.Size;
                if ((parent != ctl) && parent is ScrollableControl scrctl) {
                    if (scrctl.VerticalScroll.Visible) scrContainerSize.Width -= (SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth + 1);
                    if (scrctl.HorizontalScroll.Visible) scrContainerSize.Height -= (SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight + 1);
                }
                clipBounds = Rectangle.Intersect(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, scrContainerSize), ctl.Bounds);
            }

            if (clipBounds.Width < 1 || clipBounds.Height < 1) continue;
            var bounds = outerContainer.RectangleToClient(parent.RectangleToScreen(clipBounds));

            if (ctl is RichTextBox rtb) {
                rtfPrinter.DrawRtf(rtb.Rtf, outerContainer.Bounds, bounds, ctl.BackColor);
            }
            else {
                ctl.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bounds);
            }
            if (ctl.HasChildren) {
                DrawNestedControls(outerContainer, ctl, clipBounds, bitmap, rtfPrinter);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class RichEditPrinter : IDisposable
    {
        Graphics dc = null;
        RTBPrinter rtb = null;

        public RichEditPrinter(Graphics graphics)
        {
            this.dc = graphics;
            this.rtb = new RTBPrinter() { ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None };
        }

        public void DrawRtf(string rtf, Rectangle canvas, Rectangle layoutArea, Color color)
        {
            rtb.Rtf = rtf;
            rtb.Draw(dc, canvas, layoutArea, color);
            rtb.Clear();
        }

        public void Dispose() => this.rtb.Dispose();

        private class RTBPrinter : RichTextBox
        {
            public void Draw(Graphics g, Rectangle hdcArea, Rectangle layoutArea, Color color)
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color)) {
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, layoutArea);
                };

                IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                var canvasAreaTwips = new RECT().ToInches(hdcArea);
                var layoutAreaTwips = new RECT().ToInches(layoutArea);

                var formatRange = new FORMATRANGE() {
                    charRange = new CHARRANGE() { cpMax = -1, cpMin = 0 },
                    hdc = hdc,
                    hdcTarget = hdc,
                    rect = layoutAreaTwips,
                    rectPage = canvasAreaTwips
                };

                IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(formatRange));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(formatRange, lParam, false);

                SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, (IntPtr)1, lParam);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lParam);
                g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }

            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            internal const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-formatrange
            internal const int EM_FORMATRANGE = WM_USER + 57;

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            internal struct RECT
            {
                public int Left;
                public int Top;
                public int Right;
                public int Bottom;

                public Rectangle ToRectangle() => Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
                public RECT ToInches(Rectangle rectangle)
                {
                    float inch = 14.92f;
                    return new RECT() {
                        Left = (int)(rectangle.Left * inch),
                        Top = (int)(rectangle.Top * inch),
                        Right = (int)(rectangle.Right * inch),
                        Bottom = (int)(rectangle.Bottom * inch)
                    };
                }
            }

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-formatrange?
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            internal struct FORMATRANGE
            {
                public IntPtr hdcTarget;      // A HDC for the target device to format for
                public IntPtr hdc;            // A HDC for the device to render to, if EM_FORMATRANGE is being used to send the output to a device
                public RECT rect;             // The area within the rcPage rectangle to render to. Units are measured in twips.
                public RECT rectPage;         // The entire area of a page on the rendering device. Units are measured in twips.
                public CHARRANGE charRange;   // The range of characters to format (see CHARRANGE)
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            internal struct CHARRANGE
            {
                public int cpMin;           // First character of range (0 for start of doc)
                public int cpMax;           // Last character of range (-1 for end of doc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: Scrollable Control Draw To Bitmap]

[VB.Net version of the same procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309095/7444103)

Comment: Two small fixes: *[1]* Draw children based on z-index (first in Controls collection, last to draw.)  *[2]* Check if child is visible.

Comment: @Jimi it gives me error on `canvas.DeviceDpi` :( can not find DeviceDpi

Comment: @Inside Man [Control.DeviceDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.devicedpi) requires .Net Framework 4.7+. Time to update :) But I'll add note. You can remove `bitmap.SetResolution(canvas.DeviceDpi, canvas.DeviceDpi);` in the meanwhile, it's not *strictly* necessary. If you app is DpiAware, it is.

Comment: How do we extend this in second page ? @Jimi

Comment: does this create new page?