# visual studio form Printing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to print the form in visual studio when you press the P key but when its working but it keeps degrading the quality of the image/form and i don't know how to resize the form size in the printing.

this is the form i want to print

[image]

this is the degraded quality after i print the image

[image]

```
Private Sub IDPrint_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress

      If e.KeyChar = "p" OrElse e.KeyChar = "P" Then

        PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings

        PrintForm1.Print()

      End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you're using a PDF printer, you should have a couple of settings: one to fit the Image in the Document bounds, one to set the quality (Format and Compression type) of the Image <- this one is always present in a PDF printer: yours is set to generate compressed JPEG images. You don't want that, use PNG instead.

Comment: You can also try this ScrollableControl printer: [How to use PrintDocument with a scrollable Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257205/7444103). It returns a Bitmap object that you an print or save to disk.

Comment: Yes, right, this is [the VB.Net version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309095/7444103) of the above.

Comment: Don't use that `PrintForm` component. Use a `PrintDocument` and then do your own GDI+ drawing in its `PrintPage` event handler and have control over exactly what gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

Power Pack Printform control is simply a bitmap copy of the screen. Since printers probably have a higher pixel resolution than monitors, the image you want to print will be stretched and appear fuzzy.

Considering Power Pack Printform is out of date and limited, I suggest you use the PrintDocument component to print from a Windows Form.

Here's the document you can refer to:  [How to: Print a Windows Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-windows-form)