# Make VB.NET app DPI Aware (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: vb.net, dpi-aware

I'm trying to make an image file from a control using `CopyFromScreen`, and it fails unless I set the scale to 100%. With a larger scale the image is progressively offset left and up, the further right and down the window is on the screen. (Unfortunately my eyes struggle at 100%)

I initially tried using `DrawToBitmap` but that fails as there's a rich text box in the control and it's documented that that won't paint.

I've read articles on this forum and followed the suggestion of including the `dpiAware` setting in the manifest, but that has no effect. I'm no expert and I'm wondering if it's because I only have VS 2012 and my manifest declaration starts with `asmv1` rather than `asmv3` so I had to amend the example code?

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)

Comment: [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) is a free download. -- a `DrawToBitmap()` *replacement* that renders the content of RichTextBox controls and nested containers in correct order [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309095/7444103). Note that, as described in the notes, to make use of the `DeviceDpi` values you need at least -Net Framework 4.7+ (actually 4.8). --  You have to design at 100%.

Comment: @Jimi What has that to do with this question?

Comment: @Alejandro  *I only have VS 2012*  => doesn't need to be that way (do you want to work in Windows 10, DpiAwareness included, as it's meant to be?). -- *...DrawToBitmap fails as there's a RichTextBox...* => `DrawToBitmap()` replacement. + A suggestion: *You have to design at 100%* & .Net Framework min requirements (to make it work properly).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.Some good ideas at that link and I may try the community edition too. Many thanks

Comment: Since you have to design at 100%, note that the VS Environment is completely customizable: e.g, you can set a Font size that makes the interface more readable, change the Colors used to highlight keywords and the code editor has a quick tool to rescale the text content, on the lower bottom-left side of each editor pane. See the available Options in this department.

Comment: Hi Jimi. Big thank you for the advice. I installed the community edition last night and this morning did the initial design with scale at 100% and copyfromscreen for a Table layout panel containing rich text edits now works perfectly at any scale! Really appreciate the help. I may actually make some progress today !