# Wait for New Added Control Event - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button in a panel, it will call another method which will create a user control to cover all over the panel. here is the code for the panel's button click event:

```
    private void btnTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UtilLoader.ShowLoader(this);

        lblStatus.Text = "Done";
    }
```

the code for ShowLoader is this:

```
internal class UtilLoader
{
    public static void ShowLoader(Control parent)
    {
        var ct = new UcLoaderBox(parent)
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
            Bounds = parent.ClientRectangle
        };
        parent.Controls.Add(ct);
        ct.BringToFront();

        ct.SubmitMessage += (sender, args) => { /* Here I can detect if user control is closed */ };
    }
}
```

The user control has an event named `SubmitMessage` that will be fired if the user clicks on the button inside the user control. the `btnTarget_Click` will open up the user control and then immediately will execute `lblStatus.Text = "Done;`

I need to wait for `SubmitMessage` to be fired inside the user control.
I tried to do something like this using `ManualResetEvent`, but no success, it won't stop on await:

```
internal class UtilLoader
{
    public static async void ShowLoader(Control parent)
    {
        var waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var ct = new UcLoaderBox(parent)
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
            Bounds = parent.ClientRectangle
        };
        parent.Controls.Add(ct);
        ct.BringToFront();

        ct.SubmitMessage += (sender, args) => { waiter.Reset(); };

        await Task.Run(()=> waiter.WaitOne());
    }
}
```

I also used below code and replacing `await ct.WhenClicked` instead of `await Task.Run(()=> waiter.WaitOne());` in above code, but still no wait!

```
public static class Utils
{
        public static Task WhenClicked(this Control target)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            EventHandler onClick = null;
            onClick = (sender, e) =>
            {
                ((UcLoaderBox) target).SubmitMessage -= onClick;
                tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            };
            ((UcLoaderBox)target).SubmitMessage += onClick;
            return tcs.Task;
        }
}
```

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Updated:

With Andy's Answer, it will work fine now. But there is another problem.

That user control acts as a Modal and it will appear when it is needed. I'm adding and replacing it with the old message box system. the button may call a method that inserts into the database or another method that logs into a text file. inside these methods may the user control show as a modal on its parent control.

I can add the parent parameter into those methods and pass the parent control into them so whenever they want to show the modal, they can, and if not, nothing.

But converting all of these methods into async-await and converting all of the button events's into async-await is very hard.

Comment: Can't you simply move `lblStatus.Text = "Done";` in the event handler: `ct.SubmitMessage += (o, a) => {  lblStatus.Text = "Done"; };`. Is it because `UtilLoader` doesn't know about `lblStatus`? What's `lblStatus`'s Parent? Since you're passing a Control instance to `ShowLoader()`, you can also pass it an Action which will set the Label in the event handler. Or the Label instance itself (I'd prefer the former, so you reference the target Control in one place only).

Comment: @Jimi `lblStatus.Text = "Done";` is just a simple example, there are some other codes with some specific settings which should execute after the `UtilLoader`. passing the codes as an action into the `UtilLoader` will cause me some other big problems. the lblStatus's Parent is the panel which conatins it.

Comment: so you essentially want a modal user control... similar to `ShowDialog`

Comment: What's the difference in running that code in the Action delegate instead of adding the same code right after `UtilLoader.ShowLoader(this);`? Aren't you trying to execute code after the UC raise the `SubmitMessage` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
public class SomeLoader
{
    // no reason to use async void here. Use Task.
    public static async Task LoadSomethingAsync(Control parent)
    {
        using(var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            var c = new TestModalUserCtrl();
            parent.Controls.Add(c);

            c.SomeMessage += (s, e) =>
            {
                ev.Set(); // use Set
            };

            await Task.Run(() => ev.WaitOne());

            parent.Controls.Remove(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to make it `async`, then await on it from the caller:

```
// make sure your event is async
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // await for the job to finish
    await SomeLoader.LoadSomethingAsync(this);

    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

Comment: what if the button event calls a method and inside that method, we decide to create the modal or not?

Comment: @InsideMan -- that's fine -- as long as the method is `async Task`, then it will be fine. If you want to update your question to illustrate what you mean, i'll update my answer

Comment: I do not want to `async-await` the button event and I want the inner methods to handle this situation.